# How to find which button was used on the submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am trying to distinguish which button/link was pressed on the submit. I am generating a product to purchase like so:

```
var product = JSON.parse(data);

var html = '';
html += '<div>'
html += '<form class="buy-product" >';
html += '<div class="product_title">Price</div>'
html += '<div class= "product_info_2" >' + product['product_price'] + '</div>'
html += '<div class= "product_info_2" >' + product['product_description'] + '</div>'
html += '<div class="product_title">Image</div>'
html += '<div class= "product_info_2" >Coming Soon</div>'
html += '<input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="' + product['product_id'] + '" id="product_id" >'
html += '<a href="#" class="button rightButton submit" id="add-to-cart-button" style="margin-right:100px;" >Add To Cart!</a>'
html += '<a href="#" class="button rightButton submit" id="view-product-button" >Buy It Now!</a>'
html += '</form>'
html += '</div>'

$('#product .toolbar h1').html(product['product_name']);
$('#view-product').html(html);​
```

And I am getting that the product was submitted like this:

```
$('#product').on('submit', '.buy-product', function() {
    var product_id = $(this).children('input[name=product_id]').val();
    createPurchaseView(product_id);
    jQT.goTo('#purchase');
});​
```

But how can I distinguish between the 'Add To Cart' vs the 'Buy Now' being pressed?

Comment: If you use `<button type=submit>` instead of `<a>` tags then the "name" attribute of the button is submitted with the parameter list, with the value of the parameter taken from the "value" attribute.

Comment: Dave's solution will work for you. Might I also suggest using script templates instead of generating raw HTML using javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the event argument to your callback and check its target property.

```
$('#product').on('click', '.buy-product', function(event) {
    var $target = $(event.target);
    if($target.is("#add-to-cart-button") {
        //Add to cart
    } else if($target.is("#view-product-button") {
        //Buy it now
    }
});
```

[jQuery event.target page](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/)

Comment: I get this: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLFormElement> has no method 'is'

Comment: Oops.  Updated the reference.

Comment: Hmmm still have issues. Always goes to else. Trying to figure it out.  alert(event.target.id);
     if($target.is("#add-to-cart-button")) {
      alert('Ook');
     } else if($target.is("#view-product-button")) {
      alert('Ook 123');
     } else {
      var product_id = $(this).children('input[name=product_id]').val();
      createPurchaseView(product_id);
      jQT.goTo('#purchase');
     }

Comment: And this is always blank : event.target.id

Comment: Ok, I figured out why this wasn't working.  On a submit event, the event.target is the form, not the button.  So if you change the action in the 'on' function to be 'click' instead of 'submit', this will work fine.  See code here: http://jsfiddle.net/kg8sr/11/

Answer (score 0):

Add click handlers to the buttons in which you add some data to the element that was clicked eg:

```
$('.button').click(function(){
 $(this).data("clicked", true);
});
```

Then check for this data in the submit event:

```
$('.button').each(function(){
 if ($(this).data("clicked")) alert("it was me");
});
```

Comment: Dave's answer is probably better, so ignore this